# How to echo PHP code inside switch case

Tags: php

So I have this code that should display price in one case and "Paid" text in other:

```
<?php
switch($order['status'])
{
    case 0:
        echo  
        '<div class="paiment">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>More text</li>
                    <li>More text</li>
                    <li>Important text:
                        <?php foreach($something as $item): ?>
                            <?php
                            $unitPrice = HelperItem::displayItemPrice($item["price"], true, $configuration);
                            ?>            
                            <?php echo $unitPrice; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>'
        ;
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'Paid';
        break;
}
?>
```

I need some way to make this "foreach" work inside "echo". I've tried with removing "" and doing something like this: echo 'xxxx' . code . 'xxxx' but all I got was errors. Is it even possible to make this work?

Comment: Is there some reason you have to use a switch? It seems strange, especially if you only have 2 cases.

Comment: that is a part of a code from jooma component, and there are more cases, i just simplified code for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, just need to break things up around the `foreach`:

```
<?php
switch($order['status'])
{
    case 0:
        echo  
        '<div class="paiment">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>More text</li>
                    <li>More text</li>
                    <li>Important text:';
                        foreach($something as $item)
                            echo HelperItem::displayItemPrice($item["price"], true, $configuration);
                    echo '</li>
                </ul>
        </div>'
        ;
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'Paid';
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: In other words, have PHP, not HTML as the _primary_ language.  Never (except once at the beginning) say `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot echo a foreach. Maybe try something like:

```
echo "xxxx";
foreach(){ }
echo "xxxx";
```